# SymmetricDS: Failover of master node

Tags: symmetricds

I inherited a setup that is using SymmetricDS 3.7 to sync a SQL Server database (call this machine SQL1) to a Mariadb copy. SQL1 also hosts my Master Symmetric Node. I use SQL server replication to back up the same database on another SQL Server machine (SQL2).

In the event that my SQL1 fails, I would like failover to SQL2 as the Symmetric Master Node, and continue Symmetric sync to mariadb (without redoing the initial provision to mariadb).

I have been scouring the official documents, forums, and SO for any clues as to how this might be handled. At the moment, I'm thinking I will either need to:

- A) SQL Server replicate SQL1's Symmetric database (i.e. the one containing the sym_data and other tables), so that SQL2 has ~2s old copy, OR
- B) Have my replication copy (SQL2) Symmetric sync from SQL1, and (somehow?) make it become the Master Node should db1 fail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL1 When fails will be unavailable for symmetricds anyway. So just change the db URL to hit the replicated SQL2. To be sure that symmetricds stays intact move it to a third machine

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Boris. If I understand correctly, I can stop Symmetric on SQL1, move it to another machine, and point it to the existing Symmetric database on SQL1. If the case of a SQL1 failure, SQL2's copy of SymmetricDB may be slightly behind, but that should be recoverable?

Comment: Yes. That's your best shot

Comment: one last question - to replicate Symmetric's database, It's going to write-lock Symmetric's tables. Is it safe to just stop the Symmetric service on SQL1 , or do I need to make sure that no writes are being made to the database that I'm replicating with Symmetric as well?

Comment: write-lock will slow down symmetricDs. Can't you replicate the setup and test?

Comment: This is the SQL-server replication of the symmetric database from SQL1 to SQL2. A symmetric slowdown is acceptable to me during this process. I was planning to disable the symmetric service to avoid having write-locks interfere with Symmetric. It sounds like I can pause Symmetric service on the master Node, and it will catch up when the service is restarted. I will test the actual 'failover' procedure after, once I have the copy on SQL2.